# Python pandas column convert minutes to second

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have pandas like below:

```
    Runner  time
1   A      3.05.3   #( 3 minute 5 second and 3 millisecond)
2   B      2.50.2   #( 2 minute 50 second and 2 millisecond)
```

Actually I want to compare the time so I want to change to time column to second unit or millisecond unit.
How can I do it in pandas?
I am thinking if can I `strptime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for seconds list comprehension with converting to `int` if no `NaN`s values:

```
df['new'] = [int(a) * 60 + int(b) + int(c) / 1000 for a,b,c in df['col2'].str.split('.')]
```

Another solution is [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) values with `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and process it:

```
df1 = df['col2'].str.split('.', expand=True).astype(int)
df['new'] = df1[0] * 60 + df1[1] + df1[2] / 1000
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1    col2      new
0    A  3.05.3  185.003
1    B  2.50.2  170.002
```

And for `miliseconds` multiple by `1000`:

```
df['new'] *= 1000
print (df)
  col1    col2       new
0    A  3.05.3  185003.0
1    B  2.50.2  170002.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to perform this calculation for you. For convenience, you can wrap this in a function and apply via [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html).

```
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Runner': ['A', 'B'],
                   'time': ['3.05.3', '2.50.2']})

def seconder(x):
    mins, secs, millis = map(float, x.split('.'))
    td = timedelta(minutes=mins, seconds=secs, milliseconds=millis)
    return td.total_seconds()

df['seconds'] = df['time'].apply(seconder)

print(df)

  Runner    time  seconds
0      A  3.05.3  185.003
1      B  2.50.2  170.002
```

Comment: your answer also working, you also let me know can apply function in the pandas thx